# How to prove every row-echelon matrix is upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the Nicholson's linear algebra book, I encountered this statement:

> Every row-echelon matrix is upper triangular

I tried to prove that using the three conditions for row-echelon form but didn't get result.

This is the definition of the row-echelon form:
[image]

Comment: What is the definition of a row-echelon matrix that you know of?

Comment: @user587126 I added that.

Comment: so isn't it obvious from the definition?

Comment: @user587126 For me it is not obvious. I need a precise argument.

Comment: an upper triangular matrix is a matrix with only $0$s as entries below the diagonal,no matter what the other elements are. For a row echelon matrix,the non zero rows starts with a 1 whose position  is right next to that of the row above it,i.e it contains $1$ and $0$ in its diagonal and all the elements below diagonal is $0$

Comment: @user587126 Is this a valid proof? I think we should use induction instead.

Comment: it comes directly from the definition. You are needlessly complicating things

Comment: Surely it comes directly from the definition, but OP wants a fully written argument for it. What seems as obvious to you may not be obvious for some others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that a matrix $A$ is in row echelon form. Let $r$ be the number of nonzero rows in $A$. Let $a_{ij_{i}}$ denote the leading $1$ in row $i$.

Notice that $1\leq j_{1} < j_{2} <\ ...<\ j_{r-1}< j_{r} \ $and so $n\leq j_n$ for $n=1,2,...,r$.

Also, for rows $i\leq r,\ $ $a_{ik} = 0$ for $k<j_{i} \implies a_{ik} = 0 \ $ for $k < i\ $ since $i\leq j_i$.

Lastly, rows $i>r$ are zero rows, so $a_{ik} = 0$ for $k<i$.

$\therefore A$ is an upper triangular matrix.